# Clean CSS: Use divs in gridsystem for desktop, outside of gridsystem for mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I am trying to make a line under my heading that is 4 different colors.

For desktop I want it to go with my responsive grid: [image: like this] 
For mobile I want it to go full-width: [image: like this]

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class=" row">
        <div class="col-3 center">
            <img src="assets/arteveldelogo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 hidden-sm right">
            <h1 class="font-heavy">
                Beeldbank Mediatheek Mariakerke
            </h1>
            <ul class="font-heavy">
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Collecties </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Tentoonstellingen </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Klassen </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="line orangeline"></div>
        <div class="line blueline"></div>
        <div class="line magentaline"></div>
        <div class="line greenline"></div>
</header>
```

So my lines ar outside my gridsystem right now, and working fine for my mobile design, just not the way I want them for my desktop. When I put the lines inside a .row that's in a .container, they work for desktopdesign, not for mobile design. 
My Sass is

```
.line{
 margin-top: 1rem;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width: 25%;
 }
.orangeline{
 border-bottom: 1px solid $orange;
 @media only screen and (min-width:45em){
  border-bottom: 4px solid $orange;
}
```

(blueline, magentaline & greenline are all the same, but with there own colorvariable)

Is there a clean way to do is (using only css and html)? 
Thanks!

Comment: 1. Use Bootstrap 2. Create four equal columns 3. Set the high of the columns to be around `50px`. 4 Set each column to a different colour.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. That's kind of what I do for my desktop-version. Only the 4 columns are in a container that has an 80% width (think bootstrap-container also works like this, am I wrong?), for mobile I want them to be 100%, so put them out of the container. 
But making 2 versions (an 'in-container'-version that's visible on desktop and an 'out-container'-version that's visible on mobile) in my html just seems way tot dirty.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Annelien check out how to work with Bootstrap `columns` you can set them to look differently in mobile and desktop

Comment: made a fiddle over here: https://jsfiddle.net/uhw8L742/2/
Will def check for possibilities with bootstrap, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a multi-stop, linear gradient? The [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients) is excellent and this approach simplifies your `HTML` to a single element.

```css
:root {
  --orange: #EE9900;
  --blue: #00AACC;
  --magenta: #CC0077;
  --green: #BBCC00;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    var(--orange) 25%, var(--blue) 25%, 
    var(--blue) 50%, var(--magenta) 50%,
    var(--magenta) 75%, var(--green) 75%
  );
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .line {
    height: 1px;    
  }
}

/* No support for CSS variables? Fallback time */
@supports not(--test: green) {
  .line {
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      #EE9900 25%, #00AACC 25%, 
      #00AACC 50%, #CC0077 50%,
      #CC0077 75%, #BBCC00 75%
    );    
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="line" role="presentation">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dx9gyn2s/